# How to change text-decoration to underline when hovering the a element, if the a element is below another element with position absolute?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create `<input type=file>` that is hidden. Then, use the `a` element to output `Or choose your files`.

The problem is:

1. When I hover over the text, the text won't be underlined.
2. The solution was, `position: relative`. Then, the text will be underlined when I hover over the text. However, when I click the text, it will not open the `choose file` window. Clicking outside the text will open the `choose file` window.

```css
input[type=file] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type=file>
Or
<a href="#">choose your files</a>
```

Comment: I do not understand why the anchor element is needed. Could you include a slightly fuller description of what you want to happen (ie what the user should see when hovering and when not hovering) and also include your code as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The `anchor` element is used because it have `blue` color from the beginning. Just lazy :). The user should see the text underline when hovering over the text. If the user does not hover over the text, it should not be underlined. I will update the post with runnable snippet after this.

Comment: I am a bit uncomfortable with an anchor element being used just to get its blue color - consider what your code might seem like to someone using a screen reader - the a element has semantics attached to it. A label would be more in keeping with what you are trying to do - albeit you'd have to set color: blue!

Comment: `might seem like to someone using a screen reader`. Do you mean `aria-label` where someone click the page, and it outputs a sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```css
#e-statement {
  display: none;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Or <label for='e-statement'><input id='e-statement' type="file" name="e-statement">
  choose your files</label>
```

Comment: I moved the `input` element outside the `label`. It still works. Is the idiomatic way is to `<label><input></label>` ? EDIT: it's easier to read yours than to separate it.

Comment: You can do it either way. Putting the input inside the label allows you to create some funky checkboxes like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp (but it's also possible using sibling selectors too)